# Is there a way to save a text file to a public directory without any user interaction targeting Android API 30?

Tags: android-file, storage-access-framework, android-storage

```
File fFoo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "foo.txt");
BufferedWriter bos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fFoo));
```

The above code throws:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/foo.txt:
> open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

In build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Could anyone offer a tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For API 29+ you could use MediaStore API, here is an example:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);

Uri mediaUri = contentResolver.insert(
        MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        values);

try (OutputStream out = contentResolver.openOutputStream(mediaUri)){
    // Write your data here
    out.write(data);
}

values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 0);

contentResolver.update(mediaUri, values, null, null);
```

To place a file into a subfolder, we should add one more line before calling insert()

```
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/subfolder");
```

More info: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for trying to lend a hand here. I have just tried your code but got null for mediaUri on an Android 10 device.

Comment: I forgot MediaStore has a dedicated table for Downloads. I edited my code to reflect that.

Comment: I realized the cause for my error was the wrong MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE.  The following works: values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain");